# Why did Jared's self-driving car kidnap him?

Tags: plot-explanation, silicon-valley

In Silicon Valley S01E06, "Third Party Insourcing", Jared's self-driving car get overridden and Jared goes to some oil-drilling facility for some days.

**Why did the car get re-routed?** I half expected to see Gavin Belson or Peter Gregory somehow being behind this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Peter Gregory's man-made island **Avalon** was built on the international date line. Earlier in the same episode, Monica mentions that this is causing problems and several pieces of the prep for the opening of the island are happening 1 day early.

**The automated car Jared rides in should have gone to the ship the next day but instead went 24 hours early.**

Answer (score 20):

According to [the Silicon Valley wikia](http://silicon-valley.wikia.com/wiki/Third_Party_Insourcing):

> After a meeting at Peter Gregory’s, Jared takes a ride home in the
>   mogul’s driverless car. **In what seems to be a glitch**, the car
>   unexpectedly makes a U-turn and says it’s taking Jared more than 4,000
>   miles away to Peter Gregory’s private island called Arallon. The car
>   drives itself into a shipping unit with Jared inside and heads off to
>   Arallon on a huge ship.

This gag/subplot [amplifies a recurring theme](https://tv.avclub.com/silicon-valley-third-party-insourcing-1798180432) of the show:

> But **the subplot itself is a continuation of a recurring theme in
>   Silicon Valley: No matter how advanced technology becomes, it will
>   always be imperfect, because the humans who create them are inherently
>   imperfect.** Judge takes satirical aim at the technology-worshipping
>   sect of Silicon Valley by showcasing how these technical innovations
>   don’t always make life easier, and how sometimes they even makes life
>   harder. Just ask Jared—who wakes up on Arallon after two days of
>   sleeping in his car to find Peter Gregory’s island being constructed
>   entirely by machines. While it’s the logical end to the initial gag,
>   it doesn’t make the last shot of Jared screaming out into a vast ocean
>   any less funny or pointed.

Comment: "No matter how advanced technology becomes, it will always be imperfect, because the humans who create them are inherently imperfect." Something that all (good) programmers know.

Comment: @JAB: I'd actually argue that a good programmer became good the day they realised this.

Comment: As someone who has dealt with computer date/time and its interactions with timezones, DST, leap seconds, and leap days, this plot seems entirely plausible to me. He's lucky the island wasn't south of the equator...